# System.Threading.Tasks.Task - cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Tags: wcf, api, c#-4.0, task

I am currently using the [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com) and it is working great with **synchronous** tasks.
However, when I try and implement **asynchronous** operations **using Task/Task** like so:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "landmark")]
    Task<IEnumerable<Closest>> GetLandmarkAsync(float latitude, float longtitude)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CalculateClosestThing(latitude,     longtitude));
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ContentRepository.Data.Entities.Closest]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

Now, the first thing I did was check the Closest Class and add a parameterless constructor like so:

```
public class Closest
{
    public Closest() { }

    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm still getting the same error. I've tried everything and clearly there is a parameterless constructor on the class. Has anyone ever experienced this? Any ideas?

Comment: try returning a Closest[] instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: Do you really want to marshal a task over the wire? Of course it won't work. This would require marshaling the delegate as well, which is impossible.

Comment: @MarkW I am still getting the same error even if I try that: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[ContentRepository.Data.Entities.Closest[]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Aliostad Hey, Im just following the example on the WCF codeplex documentation  - http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%3a%20Web%20API%20Enhancements. Mine is similar to their example...

Comment: as mentioned above why return a task?  Just async call the function (inside a task)

Comment: are you calling this Task function as a WCF call?

Comment: Cool, Im kinda new to Tasks and threading. Any ideas how I would get this to work? and yes, Im calling it as a WCF call...

Comment: yeah you wouldn't return a Task as mentioned above from a WCF Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you new up a **WebApiConfiguration** obj (derived from HttpConfiguration) and set it as the default Http configuration with a call to *routes.SetDefaultHttpConfiguration()* in the host (I'm using an MVC host).

I had the same problem as you before I switched from HttpConfiguration to WebApiConfiguration.

For more details see [here.](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/274787)

Answer (score 0):

Give these a read:

http://arbel.net/2011/06/04/wcf-tasks/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=237